# Pygame screen crashes misterioslly, I don't idea Why

Tags: python, pygame

I Was try to build a game  and I was build the interfaces normally, but sundely pygame screen crashed and  the  pygame screen window becomes unresponsive always I run the a simple program.[image]

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Yathezz")
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
preto = (0,0,0)
def set_telaPartida(tela,nome__jogador,pontos_totais, situacao):
    tela.fill(preto)
    #if(situacao == 1):
      #  set_telaLancaDados(tela,nome__jogador,pontos_totais)
   # elif(situacao ==2):
    #    a = 1
        # seta tela perguntando o relançamento
    #elif(situacao == 3):
     #   b= 2
        #set_telaRelancaDados
while True:
    set_telaPartida(tela,"Lucas",100,1)
    #set_telaInst2(tela)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have done some tests and I suspect that the problem are in this line

> pygame.display.update()

But I don't have Idea what's happening. Could someone Help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle the events, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get), to keep the window responding. For instance:

```py
run = Ture
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    set_telaPartida(tela,"Lucas",100,1)
    #set_telaInst2(tela)
    pygame.display.update()
```

See the documentation of [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system. If you are not using other event functions in your game, you should call pygame.event.pump() to allow pygame to handle internal actions.

`pygame.event.get()` calls `pygame.event.pump()`. The `pygame.QUIT` occurs when the close button is pressed.